# Нужно нормализовать 1 изображение для нейросети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Написал на питон свою маленькую нейросеть (без фреймворков) - она для
многоклассовости - там 4 выходных нейрона - 4 класса. Входных нейрона 3-1 нейрон под bias (для лучшего ) обучения. Хочу сделать 2 картинки-стрелочки вправо и влево,что бы сеть относила их к классам.Вопрос как нормализовать изображение стрелочек - чтобы например после считки байтов из vpravo.jpg имелось число [-1;1] или [0;1]. Слышал о пакете sklearn.preprocessing там вроде можно как то это сделать или каким нибудь другим способом, можно код)?

Пока наработки такие

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
X_scale = StandardScaler()


with open("vpravo.jpg",'rb') as f:
    b=f.read()

print(b)
b=float(b)
X = X_scale.fit_transform(b)#не работает


print(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

Сдела нормализацию каждого байта изображения так:

```
with open("ko1.jpg",'rb') as f:
    b1=f.read()


l=[]#сюда пишу
for j in b1:
 l.append(float(j)/255) #здесь нормализую байты/пикселы
```